# Google Maps API Grey Screen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have copied and pasted the code from Google's documentation and inserted my own API key. On load, the map flashes for a brief second and then disappears for some reason. Have tried searching SO for insight to no avail.

```
<script>
  (g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})({
    key: "REDACTED",
    v: "weekly",
  });


  async function initMap() {
    const
      { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary('maps')
    map = new Map(document.querySelector('#main > div:first-child > section:nth-child(1)'), {
      center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
      zoom: 8,
    })
    // google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  }

  initMap()
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, given that you are using the right HTML element (not found in the code you posted) and that you have declared a height for the map container in CSS (not found in the code you posted).

```js
(g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})({
    key: "AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk",
    v: "weekly",
  });

async function initMap() {
  const {
    Map
  } = await google.maps.importLibrary('maps')
  map = new Map(document.querySelector('#map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8,
  })
}

initMap()
```

```css
#map {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map">

</div>
```

Comment: i have used the right element and applied a height; this is why im assuming its loading properly for a moment until either becoming distorted or obscured. i guess ill have to analyze the rest of the code if we decide to use gmaps. right now, ive switched to testing with mapbox. the same issue happens, even if im not viewing the mobile version from dev console